# why does max() only return one value

Tags: python-2.7

Even though the strings have the same value why does max return only the first

```
def high(x):
    return max(x.split(), key=lambda z: sum(ord(y) - 96 for y in z))
high('acbdefg, gfedcba')
```

Comment: what were you planning to do in this part of the code `key=lambda z: sum(ord(y) - 96 for y in z`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i got your question right, but when you give **x.split()** the comma is also getting added to first string.
here,

```
x = 'acbdefg, gfedcba'
x.split()
['acbdefg,', 'gfedcba'] (Note the comma in first element)
```

So when you are calculating the total, comma's ASCII value is also getting added